# What are voltages at these points in this opamp circuit equal?

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

I know V1 is equal to V2 because my professor  said there is no current flowing between the two points, because there is infinite resistance. But if there is really large resisitance, shouldn't the volage also be very large?

Second, I don't know why V2 is Vs. I know there is a ground symbol, but it's not on the branch where the battery is.

Comment: There is a schematic button on the editor toolbar. It is very easy to use. Note that your schematic doesn't show the power connections to the opamp (and this may cause some of your confusion). "*there is a ground symbol, but it's not on the branch where the battery is.*" Yes it is. The ground connection is connected to all three of the branches at the bottom of your circuit. \$ V_S \$ is a "voltage source" - it is not a battery - and just represents a voltage signal on the input.

Comment: Here's a great video about OpAmp basics: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7FYHt5XviKc&t=3

Answer (score 1):

> But if there is really large resisitance, shouldn't the volage also be very large?

Normally, a large resistance between two points means there's no strict relation between the voltages at the two points. They could be anything. One higher than the other, the other way around, or nearly equal, without a lot of current flowing. So there's no reason it should be one way or the other.

In this case, though, there's an amplifier connected so that its output controls the voltage at V2 (through the resistor divider made up by two resistors that you didn't give names to so I can't tell you which ones), and there's a negative feedback circuit established.

If V1 gets higher than V2, then the output of the amplifier goes up, which increases the voltage at V2.

If V2 gets higher than V1, then the output of the amplifier goes down, which reduces the voltage at V2.

Only when the voltage at V1 and V2 are equal is the circuit stable.

> Second, I don't know why V2 is Vs.

Because the Voltage at V1 is Vs, and the feedback I just talked about forces V2 equal to V1.

Comment: My professor never talks about that feedback reason. He just say no curent flow through because of a inifinite resistance.

Comment: There's two things, that aren't especially related: 1. no current flows into the inputs because they are designed with very high input impedance. 2. The voltages are equal because of the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is V2 equal to Vs?

It sometimes isn't. But, when the amplifier circuit is working properly, it is, because of the amplifier feedback action.

There are many question on Electronics Stack Exchange which ask effectively 'why is V2 not equal to Vs?' and the answer is usually 'because in your configuration, the amplifier isn't working properly', and usually that's because the amplifier input or output voltages are outside the range permitted for them by the power supply and particular type of amplifier (it's easy to do!)

An operational amplifier is often described as doing 'whatever is needed on the output to bring the input voltages to the same voltage', and it has a lot of internal gain to allow it to do that, as long as it's connected the right way round, with negative feedback. Your diagram shows the output connected back to the -ve input, which is the correct way round. If instead the output went to the +ve input, positive feedback would send the output to one or the other rail, and there would always be a difference between the two inputs.

In a correctly connected, correctly working negative feedback amplifier, no current would flow between the two inputs because *they are at the same voltage*, regardless of the resistance between them. Any resistor with zero voltage across it carries zero current. In practice, opamps are built with a high input resistance to make them easier to drive, to reduce their input bias current so that it can be supplied through large resistors with negligible voltage drop.

From what you say, it sounds like your tutor has gone beyond 'simplifying things for beginners' and has strayed into confusing falsehood.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know why V2 is Vs

Instead of thinking of the op-amp as some kind of black-box circuit, think of it as part of a control system that has a demand input and an output that tries to follow the demanded input.

You would use an error amplifier to measure the difference between demand input and physical output and this error amplifier would produce a signal that pushes the "system" closer to achieving the desired aim: -

[image]

So, if you have an error amplifier gain of 10 you might be able to get the motor to drive to within 10% of the correct position. If you had a gain of 100 you might be able to get to within an error of 1%. If you had a gain of 1000, you might get a position within 0.1% of that demanded.

If you had a very large gain the error difference between position demand and position feedback would be very small.

Now think of the op-amp as a piece of circuitry that does exactly the same but doesn't need a motor and doesn't need a position sensor - it produces an output voltage and its output can directly connect back to its inverting input. This is called an op-amp voltage follower (aka buffer): -

[image]

Because the op-amp has large gain you can say (with very high accuracy) that the two inputs are identical in value and, because the output is also the "position feedback", the output is a buffered version of the input demand.

Now, if you have two identical resistors in the feedback path like this: -

[image]

You can say that the inputs are virtually the same (as we said before because the gain is very high) and, because the two resistors form a 2:1 potential divider, the voltage at the op-amp output is twice the "position demand".

> But if there is really large resisitance, shouldn't the volage also be
>   very large?

The action of negative feedback seems to minimize the voltage difference between the two inputs.